# vba powerpoint object paramateres for each loop error

Tags: vba, parameters, powerpoint

I write the code below in ppt vba, for taking, in each slide, each shapes height, top, left, width paramateres. Then my idea is to copy the same paramateres in vba from excel for copying and pasting the OLEObjects to the exact same places on the slide. But gives error on mentioned line below. Any ideas why?
I am looking for a reason, why it gives the error;
For each sh In ActivePresentation.Slides.Shapes.
The data member or method was not found..

```
Sub chngshp()
Dim sl As Slides
Dim sh As Shapes
Set sl = ActivePresentation.Slides
Set sh = ActivePresentation.Shapes
For each sl In ActivePresentation
For each sh In ActivePresentation.Slides.Shapes
Debug.Print ActivePresentation.Slides.Shapes.Name
Debug.Print ActivePresentation.Slides.Shapes.Height
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're running this from Excel do you have a reference set to the Powerpoint object library?

Comment: Also you can't use a variable declared `As Shapes` to iterate through the `Shapes` collection.  Note that since excel VBA object model also has "Shapes" and "Shape" you should be declaring your PPT objects with the `PowerPoint` prefix eg  `Dim sh As PowerPoint.Shapes`   See for example: https://www.educba.com/vba-powerpoint/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set statements are not needed. Here's how your code should be written:

```
Sub chngshp()
    Dim sl As Slide
    Dim sh As Shape

    For each sl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For each sh In sl.Shapes
            Debug.Print sh.Name
            Debug.Print sh.Height
        Next sh
    Next sl
End Sub
```

Comment: your code works perfectly. I added some extra parameters, to look for. Now, what is my question that, why I was not able to do the same when dimmed(declared) Slides instead of Slide, Shapes instead of Shape...? Because at the end in for each loop you also mention Slides, Shapes. If they are not same, how can vba understand Declared Shape as Shapes. Or When we use Slides,Shapes and when the without -s-

Comment: The Shape object has three instances, Shapes collection, ShapeRange, The resource to my question; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape

Comment: Each presentation includes a Slides collection made up of Slide objects. Similarly, each Slide includes a Shapes collection made up of Shape objects. Generally, things that end in "s" are collections; members of collections have the same name but w/o the "s".  We're all part of the collection of PowerPointUsers. You, individually, are a PowerPointUser, a single member of the collection.